Structuring webscraping algorithm with many unknowns ahead
This is conceptual in nature.
Currently I am gathering information on a variety of fasteners from a vendors website.
I have created a code which works okay for one type of fastener which produces 2000 results.
Right now the code is structured in this way:
Bolt Container-

Type of Bolt (Hex  Bolt)
-

Material of Bolt
-

Size options for each material
-

Length options for each size
-

PN and PN hyperlink for each length option
- Transfer to excel








Type of Bolt (Tap Bolt)
-

Material of Bolt
-

Size options for each material
-

Length options for each size
-

PN and PN hyperlink for each length option
- Transfer to excel









All are nested dictionaries except for PN and PN hyperlinks.
At this point in the code (at PN level) I am transferring all information to excel using dictionary keys to maintain correlation of attributes for each PN that is found.
I am new to all this and have no proper training or guidance.
I found this algorithm difficult to manage and it will eventually become even harder as there will be new and different attributes found, ie diameter of a washer as opposed to length of a bolt.
I am not even sure how to properly phrase an intelligent question.
My thought was to try to postpone specific attributes until all PN links are gathered.
From there, in a different sub, once all links are gathered I can create a webs-craping routine focusing on what are some of the core attributes needed for that particular option.
Basically, this project is bigger than I have tried to tackle in the past and would like to know how soon in the code should one switch to a different sub to maintain manageability and some sanity. Any advice is appreciated.
Thank you.
I tried a 6 level deep nested loop. Difficult as elements become stale as you leave that page.
Last organization iteration is nested dictionaries as that way I can scour site but store info along the way.
I was asked to provide code:
Here is my code from the last loop. All variables not shown to be declared were declared earlier.
Dim row As Integer
row = 1
      
For Each TypeKey In BoltCon.Keys
    Set MatCon = BoltCon(TypeKey)
    
    For Each matkey In MatCon.Keys
    Set ThreadsizeCon = MatCon(matkey)
    
    
        For Each sizeKEY In ThreadsizeCon.Keys
        Set ProductsCON = ThreadsizeCon(sizeKEY)
            sizeTEXT = sizeKEY
            
            
            Dim PNkey As Variant
            
            For Each PNkey In ProductsCON.Keys
                'initialize new Product Info Dictionary
                Set ProductINFOcon = New Scripting.Dictionary
                
                PNlink = ProductsCON(PNkey)
                PN = PNkey
                'Debug.Print PNlink
                'Debug.Print PN
                ch.Get PNlink
                ch.Wait (200)
                
                
                'Finding Product Info Elements
                Dim infoTable As Selenium.WebElement
                Dim InFOS As Selenium.WebElements
                Dim info As Selenium.WebElement
                Dim length As String
                Dim price As String
                Dim targetcell As Range
                Dim outputsheet As Worksheet
                Dim col As Integer
                Set outputsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") 'ccc
                
                
                'Finding main table
                Set infoTable = ch.FindElementByCss(".sixteen.product-catalog-table") 'ccc
                Set InFOS = infoTable.FindElementsByCss(".product-table-row")
                
                    
                    
                    For Each info In InFOS
                    startTime = Timer

                    
                    'Checking to see if product is available for purchase
                    Dim alertbox As Selenium.WebElement
                    Dim alertText As String
                    
                    If ch.IsElementPresent(findby.Css(".alert-box")) Then
                        Set alertbox = ch.FindElementByCss(".alert-box")
                        alertText = alertbox.FindElementByTag("h3").Text
                        
                            If alertText = "Product Not Available" Then
                            
                                col = 1
                        
                               Set targetcell = outputsheet.Cells(row, col)
                               targetcell.Value = PN
                               targetcell.Hyperlinks.Add targetcell, PNlink
                                
                               col = 2
                               Set targetcell = outputsheet.Cells(row, col)
                               targetcell.Value = alertText
                               
                               GoTo notAvailable
                               
                             End If
                            
                    End If
                     
                        price = info.FindElementByCss(".price-break:first-of-type").Text
                        
                        
                     'transferring info to excel
                     
                        col = 1
                        
                        Set targetcell = outputsheet.Cells(row, col)
                        targetcell.Value = PN
                        targetcell.Hyperlinks.Add targetcell, PNlink
                         
                        col = 2
                        Set targetcell = outputsheet.Cells(row, col)
                        targetcell.Value = TypeKey ' bolt type
                         
                        col = 3
                        Set targetcell = outputsheet.Cells(row, col)
                        targetcell.Value = matkey
                         
                        col = 4
                        Set targetcell = outputsheet.Cells(row, col)
                        
                        targetcell.Value = sizeTEXT
                        
                        col = 5
                        Set targetcell = outputsheet.Cells(row, col)

                        If ch.IsElementPresent(findby.Css(".cell-property")) Then
                            length = info.FindElementByCss(".cell-property").Text
                            targetcell.Value = length
                        Else
                            targetcell.Value = "Product Not Available"
                        End If
                        
                        
                         'finding fullly threaded table
                         Dim fullthread As Selenium.WebElement

                         col = 6
                         Set targetcell = outputsheet.Cells(row, col)

                         If ch.IsElementPresent(findby.XPath("//div[@class='sixteen columns']//table[@class='product-details-table']//td[@class='property-name' and text()='Thread length']/following-sibling::td[@class='property-value']")) Then

                             Set fullthread = ch.FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='sixteen columns']//table[@class='product-details-table']//td[@class='property-name' and text()='Thread length']/following-sibling::td[@class='property-value']")
                             
                            targetcell.Value = fullthread.Text
                            
                             Else
                             
                            targetcell.Value = length
                        End If
                         
                        col = 7
                        Set targetcell = outputsheet.Cells(row, col)
                        targetcell.Value = price

notAvailable:
                    
                    row = row + 1
                        
                    Next info
                    
                
            Next PNkey
            
            
            
        Next sizeKEY
    Next matkey
                
                ' End timer
            endTime = Timer
            
            ' Calculate elapsed time
            elapsedTime = endTime - startTime
            
            ' Display elapsed time
            Debug.Print "Elapsed Time: " & Format(elapsedTime, "0.00") & " seconds"

Next TypeKey

